# Insert data from MongoDB in a list

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

So, I'm using the code bellow to get the content of "name": if the "type": is a note and I want to take put the results in a list. But it doesn't work, and instead of getting a list I get separated outputs with each content of "name":

What I'm doing wrong here that doesn't put the content of "name": in the list?

```
def note_name(bot, update):

    curs = coll.find({"type": 'note'}, {"name":True, "_id":False})
    for item in curs:
        get_name = item.get("name", None)
        my_list = []
        this_list = my_list.insert(0,get_name)
        print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you reassigned the an empty list to the "my_list" name in your loop during iteration. You need to create the empty list "my_list" outside the for loop.

Note that by default `dict.get` returns `None` if the key is not found. Thus you don't need to pass the `None` default value.

```
def note_name(bot, update):

    my_list = []
    for item in coll.find({"type": 'note'}, {"name": True, "_id": False}):
        name = item.get("name")
        my_list.append(name)
        print(my_list)
```

That being said, the best way to do this is with the aggregation framework.

```
cursor = coll.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": None, "my_list": {"$push": "$name"}}}])
my_list = next(cursor)["my_list"]
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry if I ask you this but I don't feel like making another thread. Is there a way to filter the aggregate to find only those who matches a filter set by me? like I have '"user_id": unique_id' . Thanks ^^

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. Sure you can do this with the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator. simply `[{"$match": {"user_id": unique_id}}, {"$group": {"_id": None, "my_list": {"$push": "$name"}}}]`

Comment: Thanks. I got a chance to read the docs for pymongo and I found what I want. Thanks for the answer :)